# How to access the database running in a docker container from the same wordpress server(docker container running in same server)?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I have a WordPress server and it's trying to connect the database which is running as a docker container locally. But while accessing localhost:80 getting "Error establishing a database connection" error

i have a database container running

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                 NAMES
9f9fea1b744e   mysql:5.7   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   47 minutes ago   Up 47 minutes   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   my_mysql
```

And am trying to configure it in WordPress file /var/www/html/wp-config.php like this

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpress' );^M
^M
/** MySQL database username */^M
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );^M
^M
/** MySQL database password */^M
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '****' );^M
^M
/** MySQL hostname */^M
define( 'DB_HOST', 'mysql:3306' );^M
```

Comment: Is Wordpress running in a Docker container? If so are they setup on the same network (with Docker Compose etc.?)

Comment: Wordpress is not in a container, its just installed it in the same server

Answer (score 1):

### Both WP and DB in a Container

With the following docker-compose.yml file you'll have Wordpress and Database running each in its own docker container:

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - ./wp:/var/www/html

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "8086:3306"

volumes:
  db:
```

For the WP in the Container your database is running on host 'db' and on port '3306'.

### WP on the Host and DB in the Container

To access the Database running in the above container from a WP running on the host, your database is running on host 'localhost' and on port '8086'

Comment: Tried accessing the localhost and port 3306, but still the same

Comment: That is because your database is not running on localhost:3306, but on localhost:8086. 
If you want to access the database from the WP-Container though, then the database is accessible on db:3306